# closest partial string matching in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a database table that contains among other things partial postal codes. I'm trying to  write a query that will take a postal code and find the row in the table that matches that code as close as possible. In the example below a Gold customer with postal code 'A1A B2E' would match the first row and a Bronze customer with the same postal code would match the third row

```
CUST_TYPE | POST_CODE | SHIPPING_SURCHARGE
------------------------------------------
Gold      | A1A       | 0.99
Gold      | A2A       | 1.01
Gold      | A         | 3.00
Bronze    | A         | 1.05
Silver    | A         | 1.02
Bronze    | B         | 1.07
```

In all cases the query would query by both the CUST_TYPE and the POST_CODE columns. I'd want the query to only return a single row containing the one row that best matches the postal code. So, if I query Gold and 'A1AB2B' I would want the first row (Gold, A1A, 0.99) to be returned not both the first and third rows

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SQL-Server**

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    *
FROM yourTable     
WHERE CUST_TYPE = @cust_type
  AND POST_CODE = LEFT( @postal_code, LEN(POST_CODE) ) 
ORDER BY LEN(POST_CODE) DESC
```

---

**Oracle**

(I can't test now:)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
  ( SELECT 
        *
    FROM yourTable     
    WHERE CUST_TYPE = @cust_type
      AND POST_CODE = SUBSTR( @postal_code, 1, LENGTH(POST_CODE) ) 
    ORDER BY LENGTH(POST_CODE) DESC 
  )
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Comment: I haven't tried the oracle version, but the SQL server version returns multiple rows without the top 1. In my case, if I have row that contains Gold A and Gold A1A querying Gold A1AB returns both rows. I would want only the best match returned. In this case A1A. I've updated the question to reflect this

Comment: @Chris: Well, that's why i added `SELECT TOP (1)`. This ensures that only best (and only 1) match is returned.

Comment: Whoops. My fault. I pasted in the SUBSTR bit into my existing query and missed the ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 0):

You have simply to write a condition as the following:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE     
WHERE CUST_TYPE = Variable_with_cust_type AND 
Variable_with_postal_code like '%'||POST_CODE||'%'
```

You simply concat '%' at the beginning and at the end of the field POST_CODE, and then use the like operator.

I am assuming you are using ORACLE PL/SQL.